# Sending data from an iframe with an interactive pdf to a php

Tags: php, pdf, iframe, pdftk

I have an that displays an interactive pdf form. How do I create a button to get data from the pdf document. Need help please, been on this the whole day.

Here's the php file that supposed to get the pdf data

```
if(isset($_POST) && is_array($_POST) && count($_POST)){

        $data=array();

$data['topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Applicant_Surname[0]']=$_POST['topmostSubform_0__Page1_0__Applicant_Surname_0_'];
        $data['topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].Applicant_FirstName[0]']=$_POST['topmostSubform_0__Page1_0__Applicant_FirstName_0_'];

        // need the function definition
    require_once'createFDF.php';

    // some variables to use

    // file name will be <the current timestamp>.fdf
    $kui = time();
    /*$kui = time();*/
    $fdf_file=$kui.'.fdf';

    // the directory to write the result in
    $fdf_dir=dirname(__FILE__).'/results';

    // need to know what file the data will go into
    $pdf_doc='http://localhost/uniApp/results/fillsheet.pdf';

    // generate the file content
    $fdf_data=createFDF($pdf_doc,$data);

    // this is where you'd do any custom handling of the data
    // if you wanted to put it in a database, email the
    // FDF data, push ti back to the user with a header() call, etc.

    // write the file out
    if($fp=fopen($fdf_dir.'/'.$fdf_file,'w')){
        fwrite($fp,$fdf_data,strlen($fdf_data));
       /* echo $fdf_file,' written successfully.';*/
        system("pdftk fillsheet.pdf fill_form results/". $fdf_file. " output results/$kui.pdf flatten");
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'Your application has been updated';
        $message = 'written successfully.';
        echo $kui,' written successfully.';
        }else{
        die('Unable to create file:'.$fdf_dir.'/'.$fdf_file);
    }
        fclose($fp);
}
```

It works well when it using pure php code, but doesn't work when i try it from the `<iframe>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting sending data from an interactive pdf form to php file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887823/getting-sending-data-from-an-interactive-pdf-form-to-php-file)

Comment: Show us your **full** code where the `<iframe>` is in, not partial code.

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is. First it's *"How do I create a button to get data"*, then it's *"but doesn't work when i try it from the <iframe>"*.

Comment: I want to get form inputs from a pdf displayed in an iframe and pass those inputs to a php page. That's basically my problem. How do I go about it? and the code posted is from the php page I want to post the form inputs to. But don't know how to do that from the iframe

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, I don't know how to do that. Sounds like a complicated matter to me. Basically (with forms), you're working with (assigned) variables. Use those variables with an `isset` and maybe use sessions, that's the best I can say, given I've never had to do what it is you are trying to achieve. You can probably just `echo $variable;`.